# How to use Derived type of a collection as ViewModel in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a strongly typed View and the view(simplified) looks as follows.

```
@model List<PatientCategory>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Code)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModifiedTime)
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.History)
                        </th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                    </tr>

                    @foreach (var item in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Code)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ModifiedTime)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.History)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }

                </table>
```

This works fine.

But now I want to change the View model to another type `PaginatedList<short>` which derives from `List<PatientCategory>` as follows
`PaginatedList<PatientCategory> : List<PatientCategory>`

But when I replace 
`@model IEnumerable<PatientCategory>` with 
`@model PaginatedList<PatientCategory>` 
the helper `@Html.DisplayNameFor()` does not work. Can someone please suggest me some way out. I found I could use `@Html.DisplayName("Code")`, but I want to know is there any better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DisplayNameFor`'s ability to look into the underlying type to allow you to bind to a property on that only works with `IEnumerable`. Even if you were to make your view's model `List<PatientCategory>` instead of `IEnumerable<PatientCategory>`, it would fail.

One workaround you can employ is to simply index the list:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Code)
```

The index, itself doesn't matter, as `Html.DisplayNameFor` merely parses the expression to see that it needs to get the display name for `PatientCategory.Code`, it doesn't ever actually try to access the first item of the list.

Comment: Hi Chris, All your statements are correct. It was actually IEnumerable in the fist line of view I listed. The work around you suggested worked perfectly, in the both the cases. That is, when I use PaginatedList<PatientCategory> as viewModel or List<PatientCategory> as ViewModel, I need to use the helper as you had suggested, @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model[0].Code). Simply indexing the list would do.

Comment: Thank You Chris for your timely answer.